# Get JSON data from AJAX POST send

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I need to get some JSON data from and AJAX function in PHP
This is what i've written so far but not sure exactly what to do on the PHP side.
JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var json = {
        hello : 'howareyou',
        good : 'yes i am good',
        toast : 'i love toast'
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("no");
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST', 'json.php', true);
    xhr.send(json);
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['json']) ){
    $json = $_POST ['json'];
    $json_d = json_decode($json);
    echo $json . 'hello';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='ajax.js'></script>
<body>
HELLO THERE THIS IS AN HTML PAGEEEEE
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You aren't sending JSON. You are sending the results of converting a JavaScript object to a string (usually `"[Object object]"`).

Comment: OT: You should maybe think about using jQuery instead of native XMLHttpRequest, it has a very powerful AJAX function which is easy to use.

Comment: The JavaScript you have now will work just fine (except for the problem I pointed out earlier, which jQuery won't help with). There's no need to add the weight of jQuery to your page.

Answer (score 3):

Stringify your JSON on the client side.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var json = {
        hello : 'howareyou',
        good : 'yes i am good',
        toast : 'i love toast'
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("no");
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST', 'json.php', true);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(json));
}
```

Decode the JSON from the raw request body.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Comment: can i use $_POST['json'] or something to get the data into a variable first and then decode it.

Comment: Only if you embed your JSON in some form-url-encoded data. Which is pointless.

Comment: Reasonably comprehensive answer here. You should set the content-type header for the request though.

Comment: Ive URI encoded the JSON because i cannot send it raw. however when i do a var_dump on $_POST and get nothing

Comment: User, it will not be in the $_POST array because it will never get parsed, hence I access the raw request body via `file_get_contents(...`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use raw post data, to get JSON try:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

JS example:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/json-handler");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({key:"value", key:"value"}));
```